# Reuse subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query with the following structure:

`SELECT blah1 from blah2 where exists (Sub-query) AND Sub-query.col = 'val'`

How can I refer the Sub-query (and its column Sub-query.col) in the AND part of the WHERE clause?

Edit: This *can* be de-correlated and written as a join, but I'm not looking for that solution.

Comment: This is possibly more easily expressed as a join, or using the condition inside the subquery rather than out. If you post some sample input rows from the tables involved, together with a sample of what the output should be for those inputs, it will be easier to assist.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you're correct. I've added an edit for clarification.

Comment: Move the `where Sub-query.col = 'val'` from outside to inside the Sub-query? Hard to say. Create a nice example in SQLFiddle and we can come with perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You put it in the `from` clause.  From what you describe, the subquery only returns at most one row, so you can do:

```
select blah1 
from blah2 cross join
     (sub-query) s
where s.col = 'val';
```

Actually, you can also do:

```
select blah1
from blah2
where (select col from (sub-query) s) = 'val';
```

The `exists` is taken care of, because `NULL` fails the filter.

Comment: Good solution there! But I'm really only interested in *aliasing* the Sub-query to that I can reuse it in the `AND` part.